# how to configure knp_snappy bundle to generate a different page format

Tags: php, symfony4, knp-snappy

I'm working on an app using `Symfony 4` , i encounter a problem while doing the print function or the generation of the Pdf from `html` for different format,
my app does release bills using a controller action with the help of `Knp_snappy` , 
i have configure the `knp snappy` to generate a A4 page pdf and its working great no problem at this stage, now i  have another controller action that release a receipt for each bill paid and that's where I'm stuck , i can't reconfigure the `knp_snapp` and adjust the format for the appropriate size of the receipt which is 9cm also i don't want to print a receipt on a big page as A4. 
So, I'm wondering is there a way to override the `knp_snappy` in `yaml` file on the action controller when i attempt to release a receipt  ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution , a part of it actually in this issue on [github](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/144) and its described as below.

```
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf as Snappy;

 $binary = $this->container->getParameter('knp_snappy.pdf.binary');

 $snappy = new Snappy($binary);


 $html= $this->renderView('bill/receipt.html.twig', array(
                'receipt'=>$receipt,
            ));


  $pdf=$snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html,array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'enable-javascript' => true,
            'javascript-delay' => 1000,
            'no-stop-slow-scripts' => true,
            'no-background' => false,
            'lowquality' => false,
            'page-width' => '8cm',
            'page-height' => '12.40cm',
            'margin-left'=>0,
            'margin-right'=>0,
            'margin-top'=>0,
            'margin-bottom'=>0,
            'encoding' => 'utf-8',
            'images' => true,
            'cookie' => array(),
            'dpi' => 300,
            'enable-external-links' => true,
            'enable-internal-links' => true,
            )
        );

    return new Response($pdf,200,array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'inline; filename="receipt-'.$date.'.pdf"'
    ));
```

i think the code is pretty clear by itself.

- i got the knp snappy binary
- i create new instance of Snappy class
- i set the page width inside the getOutputFromHtml() function
- the same for all margins options  which are set to 0 so it cover the full page

  the rest is regular

Comment: Are you able to execute javascripts when using `renderView` function to render the template?